# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable

Tags: android, kotlin, исключения, activity, android-data-binding

Как только я превращаю это:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

В это:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        // запуск фрагмента Home (в данном случае он является фрагментом по умолчанию)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, ExchangeRateFragment()).commit()

        setSupportActionBar(binding?.topMainMenu)

        // обработчик нажатий по вкладнкам
        binding?.bottomMainMenu?.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->

            when(item.itemId) {
                R.id.rateBottomMainMenu -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, ExchangeRateFragment()).commit()
                R.id.favoriteBottomMainMenu -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, FavouriteFragment()).commit()
            }

            return@setOnItemSelectedListener true

        }
        binding?.bottomMainMenu?.selectedItemId = R.id.rateBottomMainMenu
    }
}
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
```

layout activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectTopMainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13.1">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                        android:id="@+id/topMainMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        app:title="@string/app_name"
                        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomMainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_color"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/tab_color"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Содержимое `Logcat`:

```
2022-08-20 22:47:23.745 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 22:47:24.746 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 22:47:24.746 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCDaemon ]"Couldn't receive command response"
2022-08-20 22:47:44.751 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 22:56:01.534 12921-13089/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for androidx.car.app.connection
2022-08-20 23:11:42.119 15868-15868/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.northghost.touchvpn.whateverString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.ru.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.ru.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:260)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:902)
```

...

```
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/split_config.xhdpi.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:109)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:82)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:439)
```

...

```
2022-08-20 23:11:42.383 15958-15958/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.northghost.touchvpn.whateverString" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~kc_kORywm37ObItXQVeUMQ==/com.northghost.touchvpn-EV0DrLrIWpwMdhR8yiJ1LQ==/base.apk", zip file
```

...

```
2022-08-20 23:17:44.766 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 23:17:45.767 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 23:17:45.767 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCDaemon ]"Couldn't receive command response"
2022-08-20 23:18:05.771 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 23:48:05.831 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 23:48:06.831 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
2022-08-20 23:48:06.831 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCDaemon ]"Couldn't receive command response"
2022-08-20 23:48:26.836 1376-1376/? E/TLOC: [TLOCChannel]"Can't receive message due to timeout"
```

build.dradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Modele):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sem.exchangerate"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    def room_version = '2.4.3'
    def lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"
    def coroutines_version = '1.6.4'
    def koin_version = '3.2.0'
    def picasso = "2.71828"

    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    // Koin main features for Android (Scope,ViewModel ...)
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    // Koin Java Compatibility
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android-compat:$koin_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picasso"
}
```

Comment: Не очень понятно при чем здесь впн какой-то, подключить можно multidex в градл как вариант, но все равно странно это всё

Comment: Покажите build.gradle. возможно вы что-то подключить забыли

Comment: @Andrew, попробовал подключить     def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version", не помогло

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, build.gradle добавил в текст вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, нужно было удалить

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

из

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">
```

чтобы получилось:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/sectTopMainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="13.1">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                        android:id="@+id/topMainMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        app:title="@string/app_name"
                        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"/>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomMainMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_color"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/tab_color"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Теперь всё работает